# How can i solve the error with installing Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm new to python , i tried to install `jupyter` by using this command

```
sudo pip install jupyter
```

but got

```
Found existing installation: tornado 3.1.1
Cannot uninstall 'tornado'. It is a distutils installed project and 
thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which 
would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

I got that there is more than one version of tornado but couldn't fix it

Thanks for any help

Comment: Try `pip install jupyter --force-update`

Comment: thanks but excuse me , what is the difference between --user and --force-update ?

Comment: but did you mean pip install jupyter --force update ?

Comment: @prog yes you are right, `pip install jupyter --force --update ` see the last command at the bottom of the doc, `-U` is `update` https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/upgrade-notebook.html

Comment: Consider using [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) instead of `pip` on its own.

Answer (score 0):

do `pip uninstall tornado`
and then 
do `pip install tornado==4.0.0`